# entity framework 6 queries have vastly different response times when Contains is used

Tags: entity-framework

I have two almost identical queries. The only difference is the `Where` clause.

Following a solution rebuild, the first response time for both queries is 20 seconds. For all following requests:

`.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == id);`  returns in < 1 second

`.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.EnquiryId));`  always takes 20 seconds, even with a single id in the collection

What am I doing wrong? How can I select on multiple ids without such an immense performance hit?

Bizarrely the following `where` clause also takes 20 seconds: `.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == ids.FirstOrDefault());`

edit: AzureSQL (live) and SQLExpress2017 (dev) on the backend. Query is slow on both live and my dev machine.

edit: In SQL Server Profiler I'm not sure what to look at, but for the two queries each has an `RPC:Completed` EventClass. One of these (I'm guessing the fast one) is 22 lines long. The other is nearly 7000 lines long. So I guess my next question is *how can I advise EF to not create such awful SQL?*

update: for anyone else who has this issue, I found I can bypass the bad SQL generation through the use of a `union` rather than a `contains`, ie instead of `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.EnquiryId));` use a loop  `foreach (var id in ids) {  q = q.Union(query.Where(x => x.EnquiryId == id)); }`

Comment: I think you need to grab each generated SQL Query and check the execution plan in SSMS. That will help you a lot.

Comment: The first translates to SQL `= @parameter`, the second - to `IN (constant_values)`, the third - you don't wanna know, a weird `UNION ALL` with joins. `Contains` is the way to go with multiple ids, but why it is slow in Azure is a mystery to me.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I'll start to look at the generated sql, thank you

Comment: Is `ids` an in-memory collection or another `IQueryable`?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck it's in memory, I get the same result even with an int[] of one int

Comment: Then it's very strange indeed. Only option is to check the generated sql as others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Any` (I did not profile this so I don't know if this is faster).

`.Where(x => ids.Any(id => id == x.EnquiryId))`